# Windows Phone - File Upload in WebView

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1, image-uploading

I have been struggling to upload files from WebView since last few days and there is no progress.
Everything works well, The button is visible and it says "Choose File", however if you click the button nothing happens. 
can anyone with WindowsPhone knowledge help me? Its an XAML WebView app not silverlight app.